# MySQL SQL query for sum of fields from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I a have a schema like this: user table with attributes "user_id" and "username"
and order table with attributes "customer_id"(being FK for user_id) and "finalPrice"
[DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzfID.png)
where i want to get a user with the highest price for all orders combined (which is basically the sum of all finalPrice values for orders, where customer_id = user_id)
Can't quite come up with a solution, so would be grateful for some support

```
select sum( (select o.final_price from `order` o where u.user_id=o.customer_id)) 
from user u group by u.user_id
```

is what I've tried, but I keep bumping into `"Subquery returns more than 1 row"` error message. Tried reading docs, but I'm still very inexperienced in SQL.

[image]

Comment: Please provide DDL (tables creation code ) as text instead picture. Also you can provide your schema using some online fiddle like https://sqlize.online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your query
You cannot use a `SUM` function like that, instead use the SUM inside, that is why it throwing error like `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

```
SELECT  
u.user_id,
(SELECT SUM(o.final_price) FROM `order` o WHERE u.user_id=o.customer_id)
FROM 
user u 
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```